# How observe the drawing of line with the given coordinates

Tags: python, opencv

I have the code, where it draws the line over the image, but here I can see directly the result.
How can I change the code in order to observe how the line is drawing.

```
import cv2

path = r'test.jpeg'

image = cv2.imread(path)

window_name = 'Image'

start_point = (0, 0)

end_point = (250, 250)

color = (0, 255, 0)

thickness = 9

image = cv2.line(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)

cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Concretise: do you want to see an animation or a bunch of slides?

Comment: cv2.waitKey(0).

Comment: @eightlay I want to see animation. What about bunch of slides? Should I close each slide manually when the code completes?

Comment: @toyotaSupra I got the same result with cv2.waitKey(0)

Comment: Remove this importing cv2

Comment: Check filename extension jpg not jpeg. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-line-method/

Comment: @toyotaSupra do you mean that with cv2.waitKey(0) I will see the animation of how the line will be drawn?Actually I see the line which is already drawn, but i need to see the process of drawing

Comment: Yes.  That what I was asking.

Comment: I did how you told, but unfortunately I don't see the animation, I see only the result with the line

Comment: Oh!. You didn't animation.

Comment: unfortunately  no, i see only the line over the image, but not the animation

Comment: previous comments are misleading. none of that helps you. -- look up the "Bresenham" algorithm. OpenCV's C++ interface has a LineIterator. you don't get that in Python. -- if you want an animation, you have to program it. calculate the points for each frame, draw the line, show the frame, repeat.

Comment: import numpy as np

import time

Frame_out = np.zeros((500, 640, 3),np.uint8)
a = 1
while a<255:
    cv2.line(Frame_out,(0,a),(a*2,a*2),(0,0,255-a),9)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    cv2.imshow('Animation', Frame_out)
    cv2.line(Frame_out,(0,a),(a*2,a*2),(0,0,0),9)
    a +=2
    if(a > 254):

        a = 1

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)

    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it but i see only black window

Comment: I used blank window np.zeros. I didn't add image. You can do it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for example. I did not add image. You can suit yourself.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

  
Frame_out = np.zeros((500, 640, 3),np.uint8)
a = 1
while a < 255:
    cv2.line(Frame_out,(0,0),(a*2,a*2),(0,0,255-a),9)
    
    time.sleep(0.05)
    cv2.imshow('Animation', Frame_out)
    cv2.line(Frame_out,(0,0),(a*2,a*2),(0,0,0),9)
    
    a += 2
    if(a > 254):

        a = 1

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)

    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @Johny. You can work around.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you gave me exactly what I wanted

Comment: you better not be copying that sleep() call. that's BAD. waitKey does the sleeping already, and it does GUI housekeeping.